# Execute code after exec* function family

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I'm new to system programming in C. 
I would like to execute code after the exec* function family, but I don't know how exactly.

I've read that I need to fork, then trying to execute code after the exec* function. I did fork my process, but the code after the exec* function still does not working.

Here is my code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

printf("Programme de manipulation de recouvrement en C\n\n");
int status,infoStats;
pid_t processusFils;

//Usage du programme 
if(argc == 1){
    printf("USAGE : %s args1 ... argN \n\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

processusFils = fork();
if(processusFils < 0){
    perror("Erreur fork du processus fils ");
    exit(1);
}
if(processusFils == 0){

    execvp(argv[1],argv+1);

    exit(0);

}

printf("Hello world \n");
return 0;
}
```

Any idea please ? 
Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean the `printf` isn't working, because the `exit(0);` is somewhat pointless. Regardless, what you posted here works for me.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes this is what I mean; the printf statement dosn't work after calling the exec function.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I make it work please ?

Comment: Seems fine here: http://ideone.com/TCkYbu

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : it's doesn't work, unless we use wait(NULL)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your help.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After several edits, here is the right answer if someone will need it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

printf("Programme de manipulation de recouvrement en C\n\n");
int nombre1,nombre2;
pid_t processusFils;

//Usage du programme 
if(argc == 1){
    printf("USAGE : %s args1 ... argN \n\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}


processusFils = fork();
wait(NULL);
if(processusFils < 0){
    perror("Erreur fork du processus fils ");
    exit(1);
}
if(processusFils == 0){
    execvp(argv[1],argv+1);
    exit(0);

}
printf("Hello world \n");

return 0;
}
```

We just need to add a wait(NULL), so that we wait for the termination of the "child process". After that, it's the parent who will continue the execution of the code.

Good luck

Hajar

Comment: If you bothered to check the return value of `wait()` you'd have noticed that `wait()`ing in the child is not a good idea.

Comment: @EOF : This is what I'm looking for. Waiting for the child to be done, and then the "parent process" will continue the execution of the code. 
This what I'm looking for in my example, I am not talking in general, or giving a general solution.

Comment: No, you are also `wait()`ing in *in the child*. Since the child doesn't have any children of its own, the `wait()` in the child returns an error, which you ignore. This is not good design.

Comment: @EOF: Ah okey, now I understand :)
So what do you suggest as a good design ?

Comment: Move the `wait()` right above the `printf("Hello World \n");`, where only the parent will execute it. Also, you may want to check whether `wait()` returns an error.

Comment: Done.

Thank you @EOF